# I want to create a program that checks if the input is syntactically valid in C

Tags: c

How do I create a C program that takes in a command in C as input, and prints if there are any errors?

For example,

```
    Input: for(i=0; i<5; i++);
    No errors.

    Input: for((i=0); i>2,(i<5) ; i++);
    No errors.

    Input: for(i=0, i<5; i++);
    Error.

    Input: for((i=0; i<5; i++));
    Error.
```

I think that the shortest way to do it would be to compile the input string, and check if any errors occur. But I don't know how to compile a piece of code passed during runtime. Also, there is the problem of the undeclared variables.

Comment: They already have these. They're called IDEs.

Comment: You can either invoke the compiler at runtime or write/use a C parser.

Comment: C syntax is defined using a well defined context-free grammar. Just implement parser for it..

Comment: Have you heard of the [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) call?

Comment: As you correctly allude to, there's no such thing as a "valid C statement" except in the context of a whole program, especially if you do nasty preprocessor tricks.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That's not always a "just"...

Comment: @Linuxios Obviously.

Comment: If you want to invoke a compiler, GCC has a "syntax check only" option: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gnat_ugn_unw/Using-gcc-for-Syntax-Checking.html

Comment: @Linuxios How do I do that using c, and not a terminal command?

Comment: @TedMosby: On any UNIX (OSX, Linux), using the system command (GCC has to be installed), and you'll have to ask someone else for Windows (haven't used in 3 years...)

Comment: @Linuxios: `system()` runs on windows too. the only difference is on windows it was a non standard header you had to include for it. (not sure but something like Windows.h or windows.h or System.h ... not quiet sure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is particuraly complicated to parse. Even if you remove the pre-processor side of it, there are still tricky parts.

If you are learning this for yourself, you can look for a C grammar (there are some in lex/yacc format for ANSI C) that you can look at.

From your example I guess you want to be able to recognize just a subset of C, not the entire language, correct?  If this is the case, you should define that subset and write a parser for it.

Rather than trying to write a parser by hand, you should learn about grammars and parser generators if you haven't worked with them already.

If it's a subset of C you're interested in, I would use a PEG parse generator like [PackCC](https://sourceforge.net/p/packcc/wiki/Home/) to easily get a parser.

As a super-simple example, the following parser:

```
%prefix "mc"

stmt <- _ assign            { printf("assignment\n"); }   
     / _ if                 { printf("if\n"); }
     / ( !EOL . )* EOL      { printf("error\n"); }

if <- 'if' _ '(' _ var _ ')' _ stmt 

assign <- var _ '=' _ num _ ';' _ EOL
var    <- [A-Za-z_] [0-9A-Za-z_]*
num    <- [0-9]+
_      <- [ \t]*
EOL    <- '\n' / '\r\n' / '\r'

%%
int main() {
    mc_context_t *ctx = mc_create(NULL);
    while (mc_parse(ctx, NULL));
    mc_destroy(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

will accept assignment (where the lvalue is a variable name and the rvalue an integer) and if statements where the condition is a variable name. Assuming the parser is in the file `mu.peg`

```
home> packcc mu.peg
home> gcc -o mu mu.c
home> ./mu
t = 5;
assignment
t = 5
error
if (x) p = 3;
assignment
if
if (x) if (y) t = 3;
assignment
if 
if
```

If, instead, you need to check sintatically valid C code at runtime and there's a compiler installed on your system, tipically GCC or Clang, you can call it via `system()` and intercept any error.  Depending on the type of checks you want to do on the code, you can consider using a static analyzer like [splint](http://splint.org/).

If you need to embed everything in your application, you can try [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) which is also availble as a library.

Comment: I am trying to create a C program that will ask the user to input a statement- any string- and it will save it as a character array, and then it will check if that string is a valid statement in C, that is, if it'll produce any compilation errors or not.

Comment: I've added a little example with PackCC. I hope it's useful for you.